# Change chart type and redraw with multiple series in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a dashboard with various charts, each with an adjacent dropdown to change the type of chart.  I'm hoping to accomplish this by redrawing the chart rather than destroying it and creating a new one.

I first stumbled upon a solution that seems to be from the Highcharts team, but in investigating, it seems to be actually be broken.  Upon selecting "column" from the select, the chart re-renders without the first series data.  I found this to be a consistent issue...highcharts only wants to render the last series the way they are using the "addSeries" method:

```
for(var i=0;i<series.length;i++)
{
    serie = series[0];
    serie.chart.addSeries({
        type: newType,
        name: serie.name,
        color: serie.color,
        data: serie.options.data
    }, false);

    serie.remove();
}

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options, function(chart){

    $('#chartType').change(function(){
        changeType(chart.series, this.value);
    });

});
```

Try selecting "column" in the select here: http://jsfiddle.net/2hLr5/

I also found someone that had accomplished this using an older version of highcharts and jQuery 1.7.1.  You can see his working example here: http://highcharts.com/jsbin/etulob/edit#javascript,live

In replicating his code for my uses, I found that jQuery 1.9.1 would replicate the chart from its original column into a line chart, but it chokes when trying to switch back from a line chart to columns.  You can see this here: http://highcharts.com/jsbin/etulob/9/edit#javascript,live

My best guess is that the data for column charts has changed since previous versions of Highcharts, but thats a total stab in the dark.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In Highcharts 3.0 we implemented `series.update(object)` function, which allows easily change series options (including type). See docs example: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series

Answer (score 0):

See my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139234/highcharts-how-to-change-type-of-graph/25146270#25146270). It explains how to use the series.update() function to change type of graphs.